# How can I slice one column in a dataframe to several series based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, slice

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
       'A' diff('A')
    0   1    NaN
    1   2     1
    2   5     3
    3   2    -3
    4   4     2
    5   6     2
    6   1    -5
    7   7     6
    8   9     2
```

What I would like to obtain is something like this:

```
       'B'
    0   1
    1   2
    2   5

       'C'
    0   2
    1   4
    2   6

       'D'
    0   1
    1   7
    2   9
```

I would like to slice the column `'A'` into several new columns; the condition to slice the original column is that value on the column `diff('A')` is negative. I was thinking that an iterator should go through the dataframe and, whenever it encounters a negative value in `diff('A')`, it should slice the column and pass it to a Series, and then continue until it reaches the end of the column.

Does anyone have any ideas to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want a list with the Series for example?

Comment: That could be useful but not the central idea I had in mind; I'm looking for a way to slice one column into several Series if a condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your idea works fine, but it will be more efficient to use the pandas built-in selector:

```
decreased_value = df[df['diff'] < 0]['A'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of this; thanks! What I could do is collect all the indices where `'diff'`is negative and then slice the column based on those indices.