# Slice DataFrame at specific points and plot each slice

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, slice

I am new to programming and Pythone could you help me?
I have a data frame which look like this.

```
d = {'time': [4, 10, 15, 6, 0, 20, 40, 11, 9, 12, 11, 25], 
     'value': [0, 0, 0, 50, 100, 0, 0, 70, 100, 0,100, 20]}    
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want to slice the data whenever `value == 100` and then plot all slices in a figer.
So my questions are how to slice or cut the data as described? and what's the best structure to save slices in order to plot?.

Note 1: value column has no frequency that I can use and it varies from 0 to 100 where time is arbitrary.

Note 2: I already tried this solution but I get the same table

```
decreased_value = df[df['value'] <= 100][['time', 'value']].reset_index(drop=True)
```

[How can I slice one column in a dataframe to several series based on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59165547/how-can-i-slice-one-column-in-a-dataframe-to-several-series-based-on-a-condition)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try ```slices = df.loc[df['value'] == 100, :]```

Comment: thanks! in this case I get only rows where value ==100 but I want to get in each slice the whole data until value ==100

Comment: So you want to slice the above example into four slices, where the last row of each slice is `100`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Here's a simpler way of handling my first answer (thanks to @aneroid for the suggestion).

Get the indices where `value==100` and add `+1` so that these land at the bottom of each slice:

```
indices = df.index[df['value'] == 100] + 1
```

Then use `numpy.split` (thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66925626/is-there-a-more-efficient-or-concise-way-to-divide-a-df-according-to-a-list-of-i/66925798#66925798) answer for that method) to make a list of dataframes:

```
df_list = np.split(df, indices)
```

Then do your plotting for each slice in a for loop:

```
for df in df_list:
     --- plot based on df here ---
```

**VERBOSE / FROM SCRATCH METHOD:**

You can get the indices for where `value==100` like this:

```
indices = df.index[df.value==100]
```

Then add the smallest and largest indices in order to not leave out the beginning and end of the df:

```
indices = indices.insert(0,0).to_list()
indices.append(df.index[-1]+1)
```

Then cycle through a while loop to cut up the dataframe and put each slice into a list of dataframes:

```
i = 0
df_list = []
while i+1 < len(indices):
    df_list.append(df.iloc[indices[i]:indices[i+1]])
    i += 1
```

Comment: Came here from your linked question. This can be reduced to `indices = df.index[df['value'] == 100]` and then `df_list = np.split(df, indices)` - since the first part before the first index to split on is the first part anyway. No need to explicitly add the first and last indices since that would give an empty dataframe as the first elem.

Comment: Great point. I checked this but I must have done it wrong because it seemed like numpy  didn't keep the beginning and end. You do, however, have to add `+1` to each of the indices for the use case here.

Comment: Indeed if the OP wants each slice to end with `value 100` (which isn't clear to me from their question) then add 1 to the indices. However, the use-case of ending on 100 for something going from 0 to 100 repeatedly, make sense to want to do.

Comment: great idea to ask a question on SO to improve your own answer on another question :)

Comment: @Ben.T I'm sure this will just be the first of many times haha :)

Comment: thanks for your answer @k_n_c and for usfull discusion @aneroid. I already solve the problem, actualy what I was looking for is  `np.split` function, but I did it suing for loop as follows:

`slices = df[df['score'] == 100].index.values

slices = slices + 1

slices = np.insert(slices, 0,0, axis=0)

prev_ind = 0

for ind in slices:

    temp = df.iloc[prev_ind:ind,:] 

    plt.plot(temp.time, temp.score)

    prev_ind = ind

plt.show() `

and I added note to complet the past part of df, which you did like this `indices.append(df.index[-1]+1) `

Comment: Code with line breaks should not be posted in-line (we can't read it!). If it's substantially different from any of the current answers, you can post it as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the problem using `for loop`, which can be used to slice and plot at the same time without using `np.split` function, as well as  maintain the data structure.
Thanks to the previous answer by @k_n_c, it helps me improve it.

```
slices = df.index[df['score'] == 100]
slices = slices + 1

slices = np.insert(slices, 0,0, axis=0)
slices = np.append(slices,df.index[-1]+1)

prev_ind = 0
for ind in slices:
    temp = df.iloc[prev_ind:ind,:] 
    plt.plot(temp.time, temp.score)
    prev_ind = ind
plt.show()
```