# Is there a more efficient or concise way to divide a df according to a list of indexes?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to slice/divide the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'time': [4, 10, 15, 6, 0, 20, 40, 11, 9, 12, 11, 25], 
     'value': [0, 0, 0, 50, 100, 0, 0, 70, 100, 0,100, 20]}    
)
```

according to a list of indexes to split on :

```
[5, 7, 9]
```

The first and last items of the list are the first and last indexes of the dataframe. I'm trying to get the following four dataframes as a result (defined by the three given indexes and the beginning and end of the original df) each assigned to their own variable:

```
   time  value
0     4      0
1    10      0
2    15      0
3     6     50
4     0    100

   time  value
5    20      0
6    40      0

   time  value
7    11     70
8     9    100

    time  value
9     12      0
10    11    100
11    25     20
```

My current solution gives me a list of dataframes that I could then assign to variables manually by list index, but the code is a bit complex, and I'm wondering if there's a simpler/more efficient way to do this.

```
indexes = [5,7,9]
indexes.insert(0,0)
indexes.append(df.index[-1]+1)

i = 0
df_list = []
while i+1 < len(indexes):
    df_list.append(df.iloc[indexes[i]:indexes[i+1]])
    i += 1
```

This is all coming off of my attempt to answer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66904976/slice-dataframe-at-specific-points-and-plot-each-slice/66925746#66925746). I'm sure there's a better approach to that answer, but I did feel like there should be a simpler way to do this kind of slicing that what I thought of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [np.split](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html) like

```
df_list = np.split(df, indexes)
```